# Checkbox not showing as checked inside ListView

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a checkbox inside a listview. The listview is bound to an observable collection. When I use the context menu to try to select all  Checkboxes, they do not show as checked. What am I doing wrong?

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableModels}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
           SelectionMode="Extended">
    <ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Select All Models" Command="{Binding 
                      SelectAllModelsAction}" />
            <MenuItem Header="Deselect All Models" Command="{Binding 
                      DeselectAllModelsAction}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </ListView.ContextMenu>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding DataContext.IsSelected, 
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource 
                          FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type 
                          ListViewItem}}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="2,0,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

ViewModel

```
public ObservableCollection<ListItems> AvailableModels
{
    get
    {
        return this.availableModels;
    }

    set
    {
        this.availableModels = value;

        this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.AvailableModels);
    }
}
```

Context Menu Action

```
private void SelectAllModels()
{
    foreach (var model in this.AvailableModels)
    {
        model.IsSelected = true;
    }

    this.NotifyPropertyChanged(m => m.AvailableModels);
}
```

ListItems Object

```
public class ListItems
{
    public string Name
    {
        get;

        set;
    }

    public object Value
    {
        get;

        set;
    }

    public bool IsSelected
    {
        get;

        set;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListItems` isn't implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` so changing `IsSelected` isn't updating the UI.

Calling NotifyPropertyChanged in `SelectAllModels()` is unnecessary since the collection itself isn't changed. The `NotifyProperyChanged()` call in the `AvailableModels` setter updates the UI when a new collection is set. And `ObservableCollection` will handle when the collection is modified (items added/removed). However changes to the properties within the `ListItems` does not update the UI unless they call `NotifyPropertyChanged` in the setters.

Comment: It worked. Thank you for the explanation. It helped me understand it better, to hopefully not make that mistake again.